# Setting up a destination in SAP HANA CLOUD Platform

Tags: sapui5, hana, sap-web-ide

​Is it possible to setup a destination URL for your own internal  SAP business network?

We are currently using Eclipse to deploy SAPUI5 to an ABAP repository but would like to start using SAP WEB IDE.

I've provided our URL but it's returing the error Failure reason: "Backend status could not be determined"

Comment: Are you using SAP HANA Cloud Connector?

Comment: We are using a trail version of HANA Cloud Platform which doesn't include the cloud connector. Is that the issue?

Comment: I'm using its trial version too. and i'm not sure if there is a way to do that connection without SCC. Download and try. It's very simple. It works on localhost. you define a virtual host and an internal host. After that use that virtual host while setting up destination on HANA.

Comment: Fantastic! Could you be a bit more specific though, where do you download it from ?

Comment: I don't remember which tutorial i have followed. but i found this [link](http://www.sap.com/developer/tutorials/hcp-cloud-connector-setup.html) and it looks like same. follow this tutorial and you'll be fine. :)

Comment: Hmmm i'm getting an "access denied to path /discovery".. even though it's there...

Comment: Can you please update the question with a few images of your destination and SCC cloud to on-premise screens? Maybe you did something wrong while configuring. and also see this : [link](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3743795)

Comment: i've now solved the discovery problem by added the adt path to SAP. Now the problem is I need to setup ceritficated on the Cloud Connector :(

Comment: sorry but i don't understand what you mean. maybe you should ask a new question about that or update this one with more detail.

Comment: Thank you. already reposted.